# Llibrary "libmigui.so" not found when trying to run an app on physical device in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am a beginner in Android development, and I am stuck for a while with this problem.
When I am trying to run my app on a physical device through Android Studio, I get this error:

```
E/e.tipcalculato: open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found
```

So, the app runs but nothing shows up, except a blank surface. The situation is all the same on virtual devices but without an error. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.tipcalculator

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CornerSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.tipcalculator.ui.theme.TipCalculatorTheme
import com.example.tipcalculator.MyApp as MyApp

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                TopHeader()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    TipCalculatorTheme {

        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
        ) {

        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TopHeader(totalPerPerson: Double = 134.0) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(150.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(12.dp))),
        color = Color(0xDAF0A6E5)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            val total = "%.2f".format(totalPerPerson)
            Text(text = "Total per person", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
            Text(
                text = "$$total",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
            )
        }

    }
}
```

I already restarted everything, cleaned and rebuild the code, and checked APIs.

I just want to be able to run the apps on an emulator or physical device.

Comment: Hi any luck so far?

Comment: Did you get any new information that could be useful?

Comment: I'm getting the same logcat message but my app seems to run fine, I just want to know if this is fine to ignore or signals a bigger problem.